# How can I have transform1 stay in same position after setting parent transform2 as parent?

Tags: c++, math, matrix, glm-math

I am developing a game engine. I have game objects and all of them have a Transform object that has a model transformation matrix. I can set parent and child relationships to any of them through the Transform class/object. However, when I make transform1 a child of transform2, transform1 teleports. Here is an example:

```
transform1->setPosition(glm::vec3(10, 10, 0));
transform2->setPosition(glm::vec3(-5, -5, 0));
transform1->setParent(transform2);
```

When I execute the following code executes, transform1 global coordinates look like (5, 5, 0) as expected. However, I want make it where transform1 stays in (10, 10, 0) globally after making a child of transform2 and have it be the same way for its rotation. I thought of copying the data, calculating the difference after parenting, but I don't think that would be the right way. Does anybody know how to make this work?

Answer (score 0):

If your transformation is only considering positions, you need to change setParent to subtract its argument's position from its transform's position, this will shift the transform by the negative position of its parent in local space, and then the parenting system will add the parent's position to the transform's, resulting in no transformation.

```
//in setParent(t)
setPosition(getPosition() - t.getPosition);
parent = t;
```

However, if your tranforms are defined by matrices, you need to instead change setParent to multiply its transform's matrix by the inverse of the argument's matrix to result in no change to the transform's global position, because the parenting hierarchy will the matrices together again and nullify the change.

```
//in setPosition(t)
//depending on if or how you have mathematical matrices set up this line will vary
matrix *= t.matrix.inverse;
parent = t;
```

If you have position, rotation and scale defined in you transform but no matrix, look up how game engines like Unity and Unreal construct a transformation's matrix from these properties, search 4x4 transformstion matrix too. The math is a bit archaic, but it pays off when it comes to efficiency and flexibility.